# Create a dropdown with Custom Post Types as option in admin

Tags: custom-post-types, admin

I need to create a dropdown menu with "**posts** from a custom post type" as option.

This dropdown will be placed as custom meta box.

For example, I want all posts with the custom type "Video" as option in the select.

```
<select>
   <option>post title n°1<option>
   <option>post title n°2<option>
   ....
</select>
```

Thanks

Comment: Where do you want this metabox to appear? I mean which page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the code I'm using in a project I'm working on.

```
function generate_post_select($select_id, $post_type, $selected = 0) {
        $post_type_object = get_post_type_object($post_type);
        $label = $post_type_object->label;
        $posts = get_posts(array('post_type'=> $post_type, 'post_status'=> 'publish', 'suppress_filters' => false, 'posts_per_page'=>-1));
        echo '<select name="'. $select_id .'" id="'.$select_id.'">';
        echo '<option value = "" >All '.$label.' </option>';
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            echo '<option value="', $post->ID, '"', $selected == $post->ID ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $post->post_title, '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
    }
```

`$select_id` is used as the name and id of the select, `$post_type` is the type you want to be made into the select and `$selected` is the post id you want selected in the select box.

Answer (score 7):

```
wp_dropdown_pages(array('post_type'=>'video'));
```

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages

Comment: Doesn't always work, per link you provided.

Comment: Works only for hierarchical post types

Comment: How to display option to select ALL post types in this dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

If you already know how to make the custom meta box, you can use

```
  wp_dropdown_categories();
```

maybe like so :

```
wp_dropdown_categories('taxonomy=your_texonomy&hide_empty=0&orderby=name&name=types&show_option_none=Select type);
```

Comment: wp_dropdown_categories shows categories, not post types as @Steffi asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Since my last answer was considered more of a question. I'll answer with more of an answer. You could use the Magic Fields plugin 2 (note the 2 because that is a different but improved plugin). You can choose a 'related type' field from the admin boxes they offer. Of course you still can excavate how it's done in this plugin if you want to create this function yourself, but at least there is somebody who figured it out.